# Entity Framework to WebService

Tags: entity-framework, web-services

I'm starting to work with Entity Framework as ORM. But my question is: is it correct and possible to map entities between Entity Framework and WebServices?

The question is because we need to query data from a web service (method) to our application, and also we need to consume a webservice (method) to store data; so we want to keep the architecture along the whole application (everything queried and stored using Enterprise Library).

Hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance and if it's possible, give me please some useful information or tutorial for starters.

Comment: Consider WCF data services or OData. They work with the EF, but are designed for distributed data.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the webservices, because the already exists and are not part of my application. I just need to consume them somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a deep search on the web, I found out that the answer to my question is: "Not only you can't map entities from a web service to Entity Framework (at least, not as easily as it would be with a database table), but also you shouldn't do it"; because a WebService was not intended for that purpose, it only expose certain members of the whole data, so it's not logical to apply EF structure for only certain part of the data entity itself.

Here is the original post if anybody have the same doubt:

[MSDN Forum - Mapping WebService with Entity Framework](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/55bd9add-d6b2-4952-85d6-23a4d16fe8d4)