# creating rest webservice on entity framework

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework, rest

#### first of all

i am planning to my project.So, i am just making research.

#### now

i have a project that contains data access layer.

to build that layer, i know this solutions:

1. creating a stored procedures and call it from my code. **This way is very old**.
2. working with linq with sql. **I read that this way will be die soon**.
3. working with entity framework. i tested it and make a small test project. **it seems that it contains all what i need.**

my project should give a web services.

I make a research about web services and I found that RESTFUL web service is suitable to my need.

#### my question

what is the best way to create web servcies on a project that its access layer is entity framework

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603398/entity-framework-to-webservice

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using .NET Web API.
You can read more about it here: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Just add a new Web API project, which communicates with your data-access layer, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use **WCF Data Services**. This makes it easy to expose an Entity Framework model using the OData protocol, which uses the semantics of REST.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792(v=vs.110).aspx for more about WCF Data Services. This requires .NET 4.0 or 4.5.

Comment: in step 5, they say `Connect the data model to the database`. I don't have the northwind database but i can download it. so, should i add it to my sql server 2008 r2? or what please?

Comment: help please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571305/wcf-data-service-exception-request-error